# linux64 extension

Tags: software-installation, file-types

I'm trying to install a program (Teensyduino) on Xubuntu 16.04, but the executable installation file has a .linux64 extension.  I've tried running the following commands to open it

```
sudo ./TeensyduinoInstall.linux64
sudo TeensyduinoInstall.linux64
```

along with simply double-clicking the file.  The first two yield errors:

```
sudo: ./TeensyduinoInstall.linux64: command not found
sudo: TeensyduinoInstall.linux64: command not found
```

while double-clicking just brings up the 'Open With' dialog.  When I run:

```
ls -l TeensyduinoInstall.linux64
```

I get the following output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 calcium calcium 71934644 Dec 20 20:38 TeensyduinoInstall.linux64
```

(My computer's name is calcium if that's not obvious.)  What's the correct way to execute this file?

http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_download.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your File is not executable.  `chmod +x /path/to/TeensyduinoInstall.linux64` This is a "security-feature" of Linux.

Dependenting on where the Program installs itselfs, you need granted rights. If it takes place in your $HOME then not.